# React navigation drawer: permanent drawer turns blank on resize in webbrowser

Tags: react-native, react-native-web, react-navigation-drawer

I've created a react-native app that uses Expo and React navigation.
For the menu I am using the react navigation drawer.

Like suggested in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawertype), I would like to show the drawer permanent on large screens and drawable on smaller screens.

The initial behavior is correct but I do see an issue when I resize the screen with the web application, from large to small and back to large.
The drawerType gets updated but the panel is blank. When I click on the toggle button in the header, it will appear sometimes.

How can I make the drawer always visible after resizing the screen to a larger size?

[image]

Minimalistic code example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

function Feed() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Article() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Article Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        drawerType: dimensions.width >= 768 ? 'permanent' : 'front',
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#c6cbef',
          width: 240,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={Article} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is a bug please report it by opening an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/new/choose

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was expecting an issue in how I used the code but it appears to be a bug in React Navigation.

Instead of using permanent/front, I am now using permanent/back and the issue won't appear. Good enough for now as a work-around. Alternative is to fallback on version 6.1.4.

```js
     <Drawer.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            drawerType: dimensions.width >= 768 ? 'permanent' : 'back',
            drawerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#c6cbef',
              width: 240,
            },
          }}
        >
```

See the issue tracker of React Navigation for the latest status:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10044